# Should installation of Linux on Macbook Air (2015) be avoided for any reason?

Tags: linux, macbook, linux-distributions, macbook-air

I bought a Macbook Air (2015), it's on it's way. What I want to do is to install a Linux distro on the computer. Before I do this I just want to make sure that this won't break my computer. Should installing Linux on a Macbook Air be avoided for any reason?

Merry Xmas

Comment: There are different ways you can use Linux on a Macbook. What makes you think it will break it ?

Comment: This question is an exact copy of this question: [Should installation of Linux on Macbook Air be avoided for any reason?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403234/should-installation-of-linux-on-macbook-air-be-avoided-for-any-reason) asked by RazGo 13 hours ago at Stack Overflow. If these two users are the same person, you should ask a moderator for your two accounts to be merged. If these two users are merged, you can still answer your own question and even accept your own answer after 48 hours.

Answer (score -1):

@The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like

Someone told me that it could cause CPU death since Linux cannot control the proprietary drivers of the power-save-system. I was told that this was specific to a Macbook Air, but on a Macbook Pro it should be possible for some reason. I can't find the source now, but I also read somewhere that Linus Torvalds had to replace his motherboard a few times because of this problem.

Comment: Please provide a link to your source. Maybe you can find your source in your browser history since you asked about the same topic 13 hours ago at Stack Overflow: [Should installation of Linux on Macbook Air be avoided for any reason?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403234/should-installation-of-linux-on-macbook-air-be-avoided-for-any-reason). What puzzles me is why Linux Torvalds wouldn't have learned his lesson the first time he had to replace the motherboard.

Comment: Yes the post was put on hold so I made another post here instead.